# Getting Started with the facebook sdk for android

Tags: android, facebook, bundle, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library

I have been finished step 3 of "Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android" from facebook developers support and this is code from the Sample directory :

```
package com.facebook.samples.profilepicture;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class ProfilePictureSampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_picture_sample);
    }
}
```

When I try to run ProfilePictureSample there are some errors like this :

- "The import android.os.Bundle cannot be resolved"
- "The type android.app.Activity cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
  referenced from required .class files"
- "The hierarchy of the type ProfilePictureSampleActivity is
  inconsistent"

So how can I fix them ? It's strange because if I build a simple activity project with android.os.Bundle works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is the holder api version that the application of this code request because I suppose that android.os.Bundle is for api 17 of android sdk. So it can be resolved by go to "android sdk Manager" and download the version of requested api.